# What does a power of $|\nabla|$ mean in the context of PDE?

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, notation

I've seen the notation $|\nabla|^\alpha f$ used in a PDE setting, where $f$ is some function on $\mathbb R^n$. Could someone tell me what that means?

For example in this discussion on Math Overflow the first answer uses this notation
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48292/applications-of-hardys-inequality

Comment: Fractional gradient, I suppose.

Comment: oh, hmm never heard of that before. What if $\alpha$ is an integer? Does $|\nabla |f$ just mean $|\nabla f|$ ?

Comment: Perhaps I shouldn't have guessed. Notation is context-dependent. Please provide some context: what kind of $\alpha$ values are considered? Where did you see this notation.

Comment: I guess this is an example of [*pseudo-differential operators*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-differential_operator), which are defined as multiplication operators in Fourier side.

Comment: I believe that Terry Tao in his contribution is mainly thinking of integer $\alpha$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reasonable choices are: the power of $|\nabla f|$, and fractional gradient of $f$. Looking at the [source](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48292/applications-of-hardys-inequality):
$$\left\| \frac{f}{|x|^\alpha} \right\| _ {L^p({\bf R}^n)} \leq C_{p,\alpha,n} \| |\nabla|^\alpha f \|_{L^p({\bf R}^n)}$$
we see that both sides are homogeneous of degree $1$ with respect to $f$. So it's the fractional gradient, then. There are [multiple ways to define these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus#Fractional_derivatives), but from the Harmonic analysis perspective one usually wants a Fourier multiplier. Multiplication by $|\xi|^\alpha$ on the Fourier side is a common choice: it has the effect similar to $\alpha$-order differentiation, although it's more precisely $(-\Delta)^{\alpha/2}$ rather than $|\nabla |^\alpha$.

In particular, $\alpha=1$ does *not* recover $|\nabla f|$, but is loosely equivalent to it for the purposes of the smoothness/integrability considerations. Specifically, one obtains $\nabla f$ from $(-\Delta)^{1/2}f$ by means of the Fourier multiplier $\xi/|\xi|$, which corresponds to the [Riesz transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_transform) (in one dimension, it's the Hilbert transform). Riesz transform maps many function spaces,  such as $L^p$ for $1<p<\infty$, to themselves.  So, $\|\nabla f\|_p \approx \|(-\Delta)^{1/2}f\|_p$.

The fact that it correspond to the Fourier multiplier $|\xi|$ is special to the $\Bbb R^n$ case, but more generally in operator theory one can define $|A| = \sqrt{A^*A}$ where $A^*$ is the adjoint of $A$, so that $A^*A$ is a positive operator from which one can take the square root. Since at least formally, $-\nabla^*$ is the divergence, $|\nabla|^2 = \nabla^*\nabla = -\Delta$ and so one recovers $|\nabla|^\alpha = (-\Delta)^{\alpha/2}$. This could also be given applying spectral theory.

Comment: Could you say a little more about the $\alpha =1$ case being loosely equivalent to$ |\nabla f|$?

Comment: I expanded a bit.